# Form validation on fields and FileUpload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm looking to do validation / required fields on a form that has text input and [fileupload](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload) for file attachments.

The script takes inputs and allows user to attach a file.  Upon submit, it adds input fields to spreadsheet and uploads the file to my drive.  What I want to do is force the text input and drop down lists to be answered and require a file attachment.

I found this link for examples ["Example validation"](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/applications/contactus-form) but I'm having a problem trying to add this to the click handler in my code.  Can anyone help point in the right direction?

```
// Script-as-app template.
var submissionSSKey = 'Insert SS Key';

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(10,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var loanTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Type');
  var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
      loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
      loanList.addItem('FHA');
      loanList.addItem('Convential');  
      loanList.addItem('VA');
      loanList.addItem('Reverse');
      loanList.addItem('HELOC');
  var borrowerNameLabel = app.createLabel("Borrower's Name");
  var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
  var loanAmountLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Amount');
  var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
  var appDateLabel = app.createLabel('Loan Date');
  var appDateTextbox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
  var lienPostition = app.createLabel('Lien Position');
  var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
      lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
      lienPos.addItem('1st');
      lienPos.addItem('2nd');
  var propertyType = app.createLabel('Property Type');
  var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
      propType.addItem('Select Option');
      propType.addItem('1-4 Units');
      propType.addItem('Manufactured');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow').setVisible(false)
  //file upload
  var upLoadTypeLabel = app.createLabel('Point File');
  var upLoad = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  var upLoadTypeLabel2 = app.createLabel('Credit Report');
  var upLoad2 = (app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile2'));

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, loanTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(0, 1, loanList)
      .setWidget(1, 0, borrowerNameLabel)
      .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox)
      .setWidget(2, 0, loanAmountLabel)
      .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
      .setWidget(3, 0, appDateLabel)
      .setWidget(3, 1, appDateTextbox)
      .setWidget(4, 0, lienPostition)
      .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos)
      .setWidget(5, 0, propertyType)
      .setWidget(5, 1, propType)
      .setWidget(6, 0, upLoadTypeLabel)
      .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad)
      .setWidget(7, 0, upLoadTypeLabel2)
      .setWidget(7, 1, upLoad2)
      .setWidget(8, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(9, 1, warning)

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setVisible(true)
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

}

 function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var LoanType = e.parameter.LoanType;
  var borrower = e.parameter.borrower;
  var amount = e.parameter.amount;
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var LienPosition = e.parameter.LienPosition;
  var PropertyType = e.parameter.PropertyType;

   //Spreadsheet to load form values to
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getActiveSheet();
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[LoanType,borrower,amount,date,LienPosition,PropertyType]]);
   // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
   var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
   var fileBlob2 = e.parameter.thefile2;
   //Grabs the folder to send upload files
   var folder = DocsList.getFolderById('0B8PHKnfhErK-T2IzRW9ZWjcwRmc');
   //Creates the upload file in root
   var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
   var doc2 = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob2);
   //moves created files in root to specific folder
   doc.addToFolder(folder);
   doc2.addToFolder(folder);
   //Remove the copy left in the root, leaving only the version in the specific folder
   doc.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());       
   doc2.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());   
   //Message to user after submit of form

   var uplabel = app.createHTML('<B>Thank you for your Loan Registation Subumission. Press F5 on your keyboard to enter another Loan Registration.</B>');

//Send email to group
   var emailAddress = 'email@email.com';
   var folderURL = 'Folder URL';
   var ssURL = 'SS URL';

   var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
   + "<P>" + " A new Loan Registration has been submitted."
   + '<P>You can access the Loan Submitted documents <A HREF="' + folderURL + '">here</A>.'
   + '<P>You can access the submitted Loan Registration Spreadsheet <A HREF="' + ssURL + '">here</A>.'
   + "</HTML></BODY>";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "New Loan Registrtion Submittal Posted!", "", {htmlBody: message}); 
   app.add(uplabel);   
   return app;   
 }
```

**EDIT - Added in second file upload and submit won't enable**

I've gone back and edited the script and modified a bit to basically perform same function as before but this one needs to upload two files.  I'm following the same code but after testing the submit button will never enable..  Here is the code that was updated:

```
//Create the Labels, TextBoxes, and Drop downs
var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
var Lender = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('lender');
var correspondentBroker = app.createListBox().setName('Correspondent Broker').setWidth('120px').setName('correspondentbroker');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Select Option');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Correspondent');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Broker');
var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
var loanprogram = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('program');
var rate = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('rate');
var ysp = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('ysp');
var closingcostcredit = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('credit');
var ltv = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('ltv');
var impound = app.createListBox().setName('impounds').setWidth('120px').setName('impounds');
    impound.addItem('Select Option');
    impound.addItem('Yes');
    impound.addItem('No');
var mortgageIns = app.createListBox().setName('Correspondent Broker').setWidth('120px').setName('mortgageinsurance');
    mortgageIns.addItem('Select Option');
    mortgageIns.addItem('MI');
    mortgageIns.addItem('PMI Borrower Paid');
    mortgageIns.addItem('PMI Lender Paid');
var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile');
var upLoad2 = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile2');
var uploadtracker = app.createTextBox().setVisible(false);
var uploadtracker2 = app.createTextBox().setVisible(false);
var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>');  
var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#FFcc99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');


//Click Handlers are set
var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
.validateLength(borrowerTextbox, 1, 40)
.validateLength(Lender, 1, 40)
.validateNotMatches(correspondentBroker,'Select Option')
.validateLength(loanAmountTextbox, 1, 40)
.validateLength(loanprogram, 1, 40)
.validateNotMatches(mortgageIns,'Select Option')
.validateLength(rate, 1, 40)
.validateLength(ysp, 1, 40)
.validateLength(closingcostcredit, 1, 40)
.validateLength(ltv, 1, 40)
.validateNotMatches(impound, 'Select Option')
.validateMatches(uploadtracker, 'selected')
.validateMatches(uploadtracker2, 'selected')
.forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
.forTargets(warning)
.setHTML('Now you can submit your form')
.setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99')
.setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(uploadtracker).forTargets(uploadtracker2).setText('selected')

//Grid layout of items on form
grid.setText(0, 0, 'Borrower Name')
  .setWidget(0, 1, borrowerTextbox)
  .setText(1, 0, "Lender")
  .setWidget(1, 1, Lender)
  .setText(2, 0, 'Correspondent or Broker')
  .setWidget(2, 1, correspondentBroker)
  .setText(3, 0, 'Loan Amount')
  .setWidget(3, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
  .setText(4, 0, 'Loan Program')
  .setWidget(4, 1, loanprogram)  
  .setText(5, 0, 'Rate')
  .setWidget(5, 1, rate)  
  .setText(6, 0, 'YSP')
  .setWidget(6, 1,ysp)
  .setText(7, 0, 'Closing Cost Credit')
  .setWidget(7, 1, closingcostcredit)
  .setText(8, 0, 'LTV')
  .setWidget(8, 1, ltv)
  .setText(9, 0, 'Impounds')
  .setWidget(9, 1,impound)  
  .setText(10, 0, 'Point File')
  .setWidget(10, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setText(11, 0, 'Credit Report')
  .setWidget(11, 1, upLoad2.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setWidget(12, 0, submitButton)
  .setWidget(12, 1, warning)
  .setWidget(13, 0, uploadtracker)
  .setWidget(13, 1, uploadtracker2)
  .addClickHandler(cliHandler2);

var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS BEING UPLOADED TO Google Drive<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);

panel.add(grid);
app.add(panel);
return app;
}
```

**EDIT-to Add CliHandler4**
I had update the code to reflect the 4th cliHandler but I'm still unable to active the submitbutton.   Not sure why its failing.. I've looked it over several times and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong..  Here is the code

**EDIT as answer : one widget was missing in the UI (mortgageIns)**

```
    var submissionSSKey = 'ID GOES HERE';
    var Panelstyle = {'background':'#c0d6e4','padding':'100px','borderStyle':'ridge','borderWidth':'15PX','borderColor':'#31698a'}


function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('PCH Mortgage Disclosure Request');
  app.add(app.createImage("http://www.pchmortgage.com/img/logo_thumbnail/6644.png"));
  var instructLabel = app.createHTML('<B><p> </p><p>Be sure to fill in each field completely prior to submitting the Disclsure Request</P></B>');
  app.add(instructLabel);

//Create the FormPanel and Grid for the application  
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(450, 300);
  var grid = app.createGrid(15,2).setId('loanGrid');

//Create the Labels, TextBoxes, and Drop downs
    var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
    var lender = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('lender');
    var correspondentBroker = app.createListBox().setName('Correspondent Broker').setWidth('120px').setName('correspondentbroker');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Select Option');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Correspondent');
    correspondentBroker.addItem('Broker');
    var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
    var loanprogram = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('program');
    var rate = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('rate');
    var ysp = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('ysp');
    var closingcostcredit = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('credit');
    var ltv = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('ltv');
    var impound = app.createListBox().setName('impounds').setWidth('120px').setName('impounds');
    impound.addItem('Select Option');
    impound.addItem('Yes');
    impound.addItem('No');
    var mortgageIns = app.createListBox().setName('Correspondent Broker').setWidth('120px').setName('mortgageinsurance');
    mortgageIns.addItem('Select Option');
    mortgageIns.addItem('MI');
    mortgageIns.addItem('PMI Borrower Paid');
    mortgageIns.addItem('PMI Lender Paid');
    var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile');
    var upLoad2 = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile2');
    var uploadtracker = app.createTextBox().setVisible(false);
    var uploadtracker2 = app.createTextBox().setVisible(false);
    var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>');  
    var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#9999ff').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');


//Click Handlers are set
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler().validateLength(borrowerTextbox, 1, 40).validateLength(lender, 1, 40)
  .validateNotMatches(correspondentBroker,'Select Option').validateLength(loanAmountTextbox, 1, 40).validateLength(loanprogram, 1, 40)
  .validateLength(rate, 1, 40).validateLength(ysp, 1, 40).validateLength(closingcostcredit, 1, 40)
  .validateLength(ltv, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(mortgageIns,'Select Option')
  .validateMatches(uploadtracker, 'selected').validateMatches(uploadtracker2, 'selected')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true).forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form')
  .setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(uploadtracker).setText('selected')
  var cliHandler4 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(uploadtracker2).setText('selected')
  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setText(0, 0, 'Borrower Name')
  .setWidget(0, 1, borrowerTextbox)
  .setText(1, 0, "Lender")
  .setWidget(1, 1, lender)
  .setText(2, 0, 'Correspondent or Broker')
  .setWidget(2, 1, correspondentBroker)
  .setText(3, 0, 'Loan Amount')
  .setWidget(3, 1, loanAmountTextbox)
  .setText(4, 0, 'Loan Program')
  .setWidget(4, 1, loanprogram)  
  .setText(5, 0, 'Rate')
  .setWidget(5, 1, rate)  
  .setText(6, 0, 'YSP')
  .setWidget(6, 1,ysp)
  .setText(7, 0, 'Closing Cost Credit')
  .setWidget(7, 1, closingcostcredit)
  .setText(8, 0, 'LTV')
  .setWidget(8, 1, ltv)
  .setText(9, 0, 'Impounds')
  .setWidget(9, 1,impound)  
  .setText(10, 0, 'Mortgage Insurance')
  .setWidget(10, 1,mortgageIns)  
  .setText(11, 0, 'Point File')
  .setWidget(11, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setText(12, 0, 'Credit Report')
  .setWidget(12, 1, upLoad2.addChangeHandler(cliHandler4).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
  .setWidget(13, 0, submitButton)
  .setWidget(13, 1, warning)
  .setWidget(14, 0, uploadtracker)
  .setWidget(14, 1, uploadtracker2)
  .addClickHandler(cliHandler2);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS BEING UPLOADED TO GOOGLE DRIVE<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);

  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Do you have special criteria for the textBox?  and/or for the type of file? Can you tell what kind of warning you want to use?  A red * like in the example you refer to?

Comment: I'm wanting to enforce each text field, drop list, and file upload attachment to be required.  So if text field 1 is blank, disallow submit and require entry   Same for drop down list and file uploads.   I'm not so concerned with data validation of input at this time.  That would be later on.  Just looking to enforce the field to be completed.  And yes, a * by the field saying must be completed or something was the idea.

Comment: "Having a problem..." Could you be more specific about what the problem is? How have you tried to add validation? In the example you cite, the click handler is on the server side, not in the client as you have - maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: I was trying to adapt validation found in the link from original post to the posted code.   Making it validate when submit is clicked..  I'm pretty new at GAS / javascript so for give if i'm not as clear as i should be.  Would this require a new function that checks each form field, like submitButton.addClickHandler(VALIDATION FUNCTION) {valdiation code}

Comment: That's the pattern in Waqar's example - the submit button click handler has a validation function and a set of callback elements attached to it. You also need callback elements on a "reset" handler, to clear the helper text.

Comment: submitButton.addClickHandler(VALIDATION FUNCTION)

Comment: You could start by copying the example, then replacing the form elements with the ones from your code.

Comment: about you last edit, you have to create a 4th handler and a 2cnd uploadtracker + update the validator accordingly, [here is a link to my demo script](https://script.google.com/d/1PV2IeuwtH3VtZkCiBI_WhmJUbE1G3MPF2x5_vfq0kRj__DPmu-UlDSnF/edit?usp=sharing) so you can see how to implement the changes.(view only)

Comment: mortgageIns is not in your grid, it never shows up !!

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your edit with the updated code that is now working... also changed some color details ;-) note that I easily understand you didn't see it... quite a lot of things in there , I had a "fresh" eye so it was easier for me .

Comment: I love you...  LOL  JK  but again.. thank you.. I took the code and it works.  Still can't believe I missed that.  I use notepad++ and when you double click a word it highlights throughout the script, which I didn't and swear I validated all fields.. grr  (eyes are bugging out)

Comment: he he he... don't blame yourself , in french we say 'il n'y a que ceux qui ne font rien qui ne se trompent jamais'⁑ which applies quite well to us, fools on their computers digging into the labyrinths of GAS ;-) ⁑(approximately : only those who do nothing never fail)

Comment: last comment : I found a 'typo' in your code :there are 2 `setName` in this line of code `var mortgageIns = app.createListBox().setName('Correspondent Broker').setWidth('120px').setName('mortgageinsurance');`

Comment: I know you folks thought you were done with this, but I notice that this solution enables the submit button when the file is loaded, but if someone then removes the file from select, the button stays enabled as the hidden textBox is still marked.  Is there a way to have the submit button revert when the file removed from selection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do it is to use another client handler with validators. I suggest to put it on the fileUpload like this : (replace in your code at the same place)

```
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler().validateLength(loanAmountTextbox, 1, 20)
  .validateLength(borrowerTextbox, 1, 20).validateLength(lienPos, 1, 20).forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true);// you can add more conditions here (widget name, minimum length, max length)

  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile').addChangeHandler(cliHandler2);
```

and this one enables the submit button! you can [test it here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxK43j2mKbOW-KJ3kHHuYGuTrtjyGXECuGeIp8FPrPPZHbe4tk/exec)

---

**EDIT**

Here is the more sophisticated option that checks all the widgets on client handler.... I reproduce the whole relevant part and update the online example - **EDIT3** : *the DateBox validation doesn't work, that's an issue we'll have to go through !* in the mean time I added a new message handling on the same handler

**EDIT 4 :** (last one !)

I finally found a working solution for each widget type, the date must contain a '2' (which will be true for a couple of years I think ;-) I show the whole doGet function because I made some other changes here and there... It works best when the fileUpload widget is filled in last position (don't know why) and in certain situations one need to re-modify a textBow to get the validation but in most cases it's working as it should.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Loan Registration Processing');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(8,2).setId('loanGrid');
  var loanList = app.createListBox().setName('Loan List').setWidth('120px').setName('LoanType');
      loanList.addItem('Select Option');    
      loanList.addItem('FHA');
      loanList.addItem('Convential');  
      loanList.addItem('VA');
      loanList.addItem('Reverse');
      loanList.addItem('HELOC');
  var borrowerTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('borrower');
  var loanAmountTextbox = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('amount');
  var appDatebox = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('date');
  var lienPos = app.createListBox().setName('Lien Position').setWidth('150px').setName('LienPosition');
      lienPos.addItem('Select Option');     
      lienPos.addItem('1st');
      lienPos.addItem('2nd');
  var propType = app.createListBox().setName('Property Type').setWidth('150px').setName('PropertyType');
      propType.addItem('Select Option');
      propType.addItem('1-4');
      propType.addItem('Manufactured');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#FFcc99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');
  //file upload
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile');
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(borrowerTextbox, 1, 40).validateLength(loanAmountTextbox, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(loanList,'Select Option')
  .validateNotMatches(lienPos,'Select Option').validateNotMatches(propType, 'Select Option').validateMatches(appDatebox, '2','g')
  .validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload').forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true).forTargets(warning)
  .setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px')

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setText(0, 0, 'Loan Type')
      .setWidget(0, 1, loanList.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(1, 0, "Borrower's Name")
      .setWidget(1, 1, borrowerTextbox.addKeyUpHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'Loan Amount')
      .setWidget(2, 1, loanAmountTextbox.addKeyUpHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'Loan Date')
      .setWidget(3, 1, appDatebox)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Lien Position')
      .setWidget(4, 1, lienPos.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(5, 0, 'Property Type')
      .setWidget(5, 1, propType.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(6, 0, 'File Upload')
      .setWidget(6, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(7, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(7, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Serge, I tried that example form, and it doesn't enable the submit button for me.

Comment: in this simple test it does when you choose a file to upload if the text and listBox are filled.  I'm working on a more sophisticated solution also with a client Handler...

Comment: Ahh, order is important! I selected the file first, then did the rest. In that case, it doesn't light up "Submit"... unless you select the file again.

Comment: correct !, but try it now, order is now not important anymore because I added the handler to every widget.... if I made no error it works in every case...

Comment: maybe it would be nice to add a third handler to display a warning message if a field is missing... not sure I can do it client side but its worth to try ;-)

Comment: @Mogsdad - don't you feel like doing it ?  ;-) the whole code is on another post (yesterday)

Comment: the only thing left is the date validation... fileUpload is now working ;-) any idea someone for the date ?

Comment: @JJones312 - I notice that there is a Browser compatibility issue with the client Handler validation process, from my tests it appears thar it's working nicely on chrome but not on Safari or Firefox where the fileUpload is always validated. I'd like to post a question on that... would you agree that I use your code as an example for my question ? It's a good example as it has many different data types. I'll wait for your agreement before posting.

Comment: Serge... THanks for asking and I don't have any problem with you posting the question.  I'm actually starting to look things over now, as I noticed in my quick look over the weekend, that submit would become active prior to attaching a file.  I'm reading over your updates and the section on clienthandlers at Google to try and better understand your enhancements.  I'm pretty green at this stuff and can't say thank you enough.

Comment: @JJones : I have had a good solution for this clientHandler solution, if you want you can use the improved version from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350114/form-validation-using-client-handler-why-does-input-sequence-order-change-the) testable [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzhtV-L9bOaUrOUdGyEw4fHWmO-jT1fhXeVpKaH68M50iNx_g1M/exec)

Comment: Serge..  Thanks for that work.. Above and beyond the help i thought I would get here.  I've just updated my original script and look like file upload validation worked..  Now on to adding a few more items, such as unique ID that increments per submission.  Need an identifier to track each submission.