# Form validation using client handler : why does input sequence order change the result?

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently suggested (in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/google-apps-script-form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload/15303129#15303129)) a script that checks if the different fields of a form have an answer before allowing to submit and I did it using a client handler with validators.

Playing around with that script I noticed that in some cases the submit button is enabled even if all the validation conditions are not fulfilled. It depends on the order in which one fills the different fields.

To be clear : if you fill each field one after the other everything is fine, if for some reason you change this sequence (starting from the end or from the middle) it happens that the `fileupload` validation is not taken into account and that the submit button gets enabled without a file being selected.

(Writing this I realize it is not so clear ;-) but [looking at the online test](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzhtV-L9bOaUrOUdGyEw4fHWmO-jT1fhXeVpKaH68M50iNx_g1M/exec) will show what I mean!!)

Here is the demo code I used, if you find something wrong in it that explains this behavior I'll be glad to know.

```
var submissionSSKey = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dFZ6M1JDekJIa1I5UEZIZURGN3hhM3c';
var listitems = ['Select a value','value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'beige','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'ridge','borderWidth':'15PX','borderColor':'#eecc99'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form test').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 250);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Form validation test</B>').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px').setStyleAttribute('color','brown');
  var grid = app.createGrid(9,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var list2 = app.createListBox().setName('list2');
   for(var i in listitems){list2.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var list3 = app.createListBox().setName('list3');
   for(var i in listitems){list3.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var Textbox2 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB2');
  var DateB = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('dateB');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#FFcc99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateLength(Textbox2, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a value').validateNotMatches(list2,'Select a value')
  .validateNotMatches(list3,'Select a value').validateMatches(DateB, '2','g').validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');

  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setText(0, 0, 'This is a ')
      .setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'List Selector 1')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(2, 0, 'List Selector 2')
      .setWidget(2, 1, list2.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(3, 0, 'List Selector 3')
      .setWidget(3, 1, list3.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(4, 0, 'Text Box 1')
      .setWidget(4, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(5, 0, 'Text Box 2')
      .setWidget(5, 1, Textbox2.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(6, 0, 'Date Box')
      .setWidget(6, 1, DateB)
      .setText(7, 0, 'File Upload')
      .setWidget(7, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(8, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(8, 1, warning);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ListVal1 = e.parameter.list1;  
  var ListVal2 = e.parameter.list2;  
  var ListVal3 = e.parameter.list3;  
  var textVal1 = e.parameter.TB1;
  var textVal2 = e.parameter.TB2;
  var dateVal = e.parameter.dateB;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Summary');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[ListVal1,ListVal2,ListVal3,textVal1,textVal2,dateVal]]);
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
  return app
}
```

**EDIT :**
Here is the modified part of the code following Phil's answer. The validation works more reliably but there is still some annoying user friendliness lacks...

code removed, **EDIT 2** final code, the complete doGet:

```
var submissionSSKey = '0AnqSFd3iikE3dFZ6M1JDekJIa1I5UEZIZURGN3hhM3c';
var listitems = ['Select a value','value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6']
var Panelstyle = {'background':'beige','padding':'40px','borderStyle':'ridge','borderWidth':'15PX','borderColor':'#eecc99'}

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Form test').setStyleAttribute('padding','50PX');
  var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 250);
  var title = app.createHTML('<B>Form validation test</B>').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px').setStyleAttribute('color','brown');
  var grid = app.createGrid(10,2).setId('grid');
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1');
   for(var i in listitems){list1.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var list2 = app.createListBox().setName('list2');
   for(var i in listitems){list2.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var list3 = app.createListBox().setName('list3');
   for(var i in listitems){list3.addItem(listitems[i])}    
  var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
  var Textbox2 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB2');
  var DateB = app.createDateBox().setWidth('150px').setName('dateB');
  var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
  var uploadtracker = app.createTextBox().setVisible(false);
  var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>'); 
  var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background','#FFcc99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','20px');
  //file upload
  var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateLength(Textbox2, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1,'Select a value').validateNotMatches(list2,'Select a value')
  .validateNotMatches(list3,'Select a value').validateMatches(DateB, '2','g').validateMatches(uploadtracker, 'selected')
  .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background','#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','12px');
  var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(uploadtracker).setText('selected')
  //Grid layout of items on form
  grid.setText(0, 0, 'This is a ')
      .setWidget(0, 1, title)
      .setText(1, 0, 'List Selector 1')
      .setWidget(1, 1, list1)
      .setText(2, 0, 'List Selector 2')
      .setWidget(2, 1, list2)
      .setText(3, 0, 'List Selector 3')
      .setWidget(3, 1, list3)
      .setText(4, 0, 'Text Box 1')
      .setWidget(4, 1, Textbox1)
      .setText(5, 0, 'Text Box 2')
      .setWidget(5, 1, Textbox2)
      .setText(6, 0, 'Date Box')
      .setWidget(6, 1, DateB.addValueChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setText(7, 0, 'File Upload')
      .setWidget(7, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
      .setWidget(8, 0, submitButton)
      .setWidget(8, 1, warning)
      .setWidget(9,0,uploadtracker)
      .addClickHandler(cliHandler2);

  var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE DATA IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background','yellow');
  submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);  
  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Crude workaround

#### > It's not perfect

The code adds a hidden elements which holds whether or not the FileUpload has been changed. If the FileUpload has been changed, it sets the TextBox to `SELECTED!` but the user could just as easily *change* the FileUpload back to having no file selected, and there'd be no way to clear this TextBox accurately.

This is based on the few things that we know about a FileUpload.

1. When a user loads the UiApp, the FileUpload initially has **no file selected**.
2. When the *change* event is fired on a FileUpload, the **selected file has changed**.

So based on these 2 things, when *change* is called for the first time, we know that there is a file selected.

#### > Summary of changes

Create the hidden element

```
var hidden = app.createTextBox().setStyleAttribute("display","none").setValue("");
```

Remove `.validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')` and replace it with

```
.validateLength(hidden,1,100)
```

Create a new ClientHandler

```
var cliHandler3 = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(hidden).setText("SELECTED!");
```

Insert `.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3)` into the old line.

```
upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler3).addChangeHandler(cliHandler2)
```

Replace `panel.add(grid)` with (the "hidden" must be added to the FormPanel for it to work)

```
var vert = app.createVerticalPanel().add(hidden).add(grid);
panel.add(vert);
```

Comment: I had something like that in mind as a workaround... still I'm wondering why the fileupload validation is having this weird behavior.Thanks anyway for your answer. I'll also add something in the doPost part to prevent the 'unexpected error' when the blob is empty.

Comment: Just one annoying detail : after selecting the file to upload the submit button doesn't get validated until one clicks on another widget (textBox or listBox) note also that the same issue occurs with the dateBox... still working on it ;-))

Comment: You can fix this issue ("doesn't get validated until one clicks on another widget") by adding `.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2)` to the `upLoad` as I have noted in my answer above.

Comment: right !! thanks a lot... all those clicks are making me confusing after a while ;-))

Comment: Also add `.addValueChangeHandler(cliHandler2)` to the `DateB` to fix the DateBox issue. =)

Comment: You can also clean up the code a little bit by removing all the existing `.addClickHandler`s with `grid.addClickHandler(cliHandler2);`

Comment: really ? I didn't know this property of the grid container... so all children inherit the handler of the parent (if I may use that metaphoric expression )

Comment: Yes, all children would then have the click handler, and clicking the background of the grid also invokes the handler!

Comment: I'll continue to test to see what is working best. Keeping all the different handlers (valueChange, click and change) works now quite nicely but testing with a simple clickHandler on the grid doesn't seem to behave properly... I'll update later. Thanks for the tips anyway, I'll vote up your answer ;-)

Comment: I remove my last comment, your suggestion works perfectly, I guess I made a mistake somewhere but now it's ok. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't see where to add a comment but I wanted to ask about the .addClickHandler(clihandler2); to the grid.    This is accomplished by adding it at the end of the

```
grid.setText(0, 0, 'This is a ')  [rest of the code (.setText .setWidget etc) ].addClickHandler(cliHandler2);
```

Also, can you let me know what the uploadtracker is on the widget position 9,0??  I didn't see it noted original code posted, but see upload and uploadtracker noted in the grid.set(text & widgets) in the revised piece of code.