# Form Validation Before Submission

Tags: validation, google-apps-script

I can't get my form to validate before it is submitted to my spreadsheet. Once I click submit it does nothing...

I also am not sure how to validate the Date to make sure it is in the correct format before submission. I have tried to setup the validation but before I can test it, i have to be able to submit and get validation results.

What am I doing wrong?  I have included the code below:

```
    function doGet() {
      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

      //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
      var vrtMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtMainPanel');

      //Create Spreadsheet Source
      var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dFF0dVZXb3I1Yjlpbzg3SXFIaklEcUE');
      var spTeacherList = spSheet.getSheetByName('TeacherList');
      var spSubjectList = spSheet.getSheetByName('SubjectList');
      var spPeriodList = spSheet.getSheetByName('PeriodList');
      var spCountList = spSheet.getSheetByName('CountList');

      //Create the form elements
      var hdlTeacherName = app.createServerHandler('getTeacherName').addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
      var lbxTeacherName = app.createListBox().setId('lbxTeacherName').setName('lbxTeacherName').addChangeHandler(hdlTeacherName);
      var lstTeacherNames = spTeacherList.getRange(1,1,spTeacherList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstTeacherNames.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstTeacherNames.length; l++) {
            lbxTeacherName.addItem(lstTeacherNames[l],l);
          }

      var lblTeacherName = app.createLabel('Teacher Name:');
      var txtTeacherName = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTeacherName').setId('txtTeacherName').setVisible(false);

      var lblExt = app.createLabel('Ext:');
      var txtExt = app.createTextBox().setName('txtExt').setId('txtExt');

   //Set DateBox to Tomorrow's Date
      var tomorrow =new Date(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));// set hours, min, sec & milliSec to 0 and day=day+1
      //Logger.log(tomorrow);
      var lblDate = app.createLabel('Date of Test:');
      var boxDate = app.createDateBox().setId('boxDate').setName('boxDate').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT).setValue(tomorrow);

      var lbxSubject = app.createListBox().setId('lbxSubject').setName('lbxSubject');
      var lstSubjects = spSubjectList.getRange(1,1,spSubjectList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstSubjects.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstSubjects.length; l++) {
            lbxSubject.addItem(lstSubjects[l]);
          }

      var lbxPeriod = app.createListBox().setId('lbxPeriod').setName('lbxPeriod');
      var lstPeriods = spPeriodList.getRange(1,1,spPeriodList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstPeriods.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstPeriods.length; l++) {
            lbxPeriod.addItem(lstPeriods[l]);
          }

      var lblStudentNum = app.createLabel('Number of Students:');
      var lbxStudentNum = app.createListBox().setId('lbxStudentNum').setName('lbxStudentNum');
      var lstStudentNums = spCountList.getRange(1,1,spCountList.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          lstStudentNums.sort();

          for (var l = 0; l < lstStudentNums.length; l++) {
            lbxStudentNum.addItem(lstStudentNums[l]);
          }

      var txtSourceGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtSourceGrp').setVisible(false);
      var txtTypeGrp = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTypeGrp').setVisible(false);
      var txtElementsID = app.createTextBox().setName('txtElementsID').setText('Elements Test ID').setVisible(false);
      var txtQuiaLink = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaLink').setText('Quia Test Link').setVisible(false);
      var txtQuiaPass = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaPass').setText('Quia Test Passphrase').setVisible(false);

      //Create Source Radio Button Group
      var radHCopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Hard-Copy'));
      var radECopy = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtSourceGrp).setText('Electronic-Copy'));

      //Create Type Radio Button Group
      var radTExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Teacher-Made Exam'));
      var radEExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Elements Exam'));
      var radQExam = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtTypeGrp).setText('Quia Exam'));

      var btnValidate = app.createButton('Create Event');

      //Client Handlers for textBoxes
      var showTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(false);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(showTxtElementHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);


      var showTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(false);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaLinkHandler);

      var showTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(true);
      var hideTxtQuiaPassHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaPass).setVisible(false);
          radQExam.addClickHandler(showTxtQuiaPassHandler);
          radTExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);
          radEExam.addClickHandler(hideTxtQuiaPassHandler);

      //Create validation handler
      var valSubmit = app.createServerClickHandler('valSubmit');
          valSubmit.addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);

      //Add this handler to the button
          btnValidate.addClickHandler(valSubmit);

      //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
          var formGrid = app.createGrid(12,3).setCellPadding(3);
          vrtMainPanel.add(formGrid);
          formGrid
          .setWidget(0,0,lbxTeacherName)
          .setWidget(0,1,txtExt)
          .setWidget(0,2,txtTeacherName)
          .setWidget(1,0,lbxPeriod)
          .setWidget(1,1,lbxSubject)
          .setWidget(2,0,lblDate)
          .setWidget(2,1,boxDate)
          .setWidget(3,0,lblStudentNum)
          .setWidget(3,1,lbxStudentNum)
          .setWidget(4,0,radHCopy)
          .setWidget(4,1,radECopy)
          .setWidget(5,0,radTExam)
          .setWidget(6,0,radEExam)
          .setWidget(6,1,txtElementsID)
          .setWidget(7,0,radQExam)
          .setWidget(7,1,txtQuiaLink)
          .setWidget(8,1,txtQuiaPass)
          .setWidget(9,0,txtSourceGrp)
          .setWidget(9,1,txtTypeGrp)
          .setWidget(10,0,btnValidate)

      //Add this panel to the application
      app.add(vrtMainPanel);

      //Return the application
      return app;
}

function valSubmit(e) {
  var flag = 0;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var Teacher = e.parameter.txtTeacherName;
  var Ext = e.parameter.txtExt;
  var Subject = e.parameter.lbxSubject;
  var Period = e.parameter.lbxPeriod;
  var Date = e.parameter.boxDate;
  var StudentNum = e.parameter.lbxStudentNum;
  var Source = e.parameter.txtSourceGrp;
  var Type = e.parameter.txtTypeGrp;
  var ElementsID = e.parameter.txtElementsID;
  var QuiaLink = e.parameter.txtQuiaLink;
  var QuiaPass = e.parameter.txtQuiaPass;

  if (Teacher == '' || Teacher == '-- Select Teacher --') {
    app.getElementById('vldTeacherName').setText('* Select Teacher').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Ext == '') {
    app.getElementById('vldExt').setText('* Select Teacher Again').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Subject == '' || Subject == '-- Select Subject --') {
    app.getElementById('vldSubject').setText('* Select Subject').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Period == '' || Period == '-- Select Period --') {
    app.getElementById('vldPeriod').setText('* Select Period').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Date == '' || Date == Utilities.formatDate(Date, 'EST', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) {
    app.getElementById('vldDate').setText('* Date must be entered as yyyy-mm-dd').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (StudentNum == '' || StudentNum == '-- Select # --') {
    app.getElementById('vldStudentNum').setText('* Select Student #').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Source == '' || Source == false) {
    app.getElementById('vldSourceGrp').setText('* Select either Hard Copy or Electronic Copy').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (Type == '' || Type == false) {
    app.getElementById('vldTypeGrp').setText('* Select either Teacher-Made Exam, Elements Exam, or Quia Exam').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (ElementsID == '' && Type == 'Elements Exam') {
    app.getElementById('vldElementsID').setText('* Enter Elements ID').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (QuiaLink == '' || QuiaPass == '' && Type == 'Quia Exam') {
    app.getElementById('vldQuia').setText('* Enter Quia Link and/or Passphrase').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    app.getElementById('lblNoSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (flag == 0) {
    app.getElementById('lblSuccess').setStyleAttribute("color", "#F00").setVisible(true);

    //Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
    var evtHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
    var vrtMainPanel = app.getElementById(vrtMainPanel);
        evtHandler.addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
  }
}

function valHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

  //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
  var vrtMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtMainPanel');

  var lblSuccess = app.createLabel('Check your information below, if everything looks correct you may confirm your event...').setName('lblSuccess').setId('lblSuccess').setVisible(false);
  var lblNoSuccess = app.createLabel('There were issues with the creation of your event... click BACK, and make the following corrections:').setName('lblNoSuccess').setId('lblNoSuccess').setVisible(false);
  var vldTeacherName = app.createLabel().setId('vldTeacherName').setVisible(false);
  var vldExt = app.createLabel().setId('vldExt').setVisible(false);
  var vldDate = app.createLabel().setId('vldDate').setVisible(false);
  var vldSubject = app.createLabel().setId('vldSubject').setVisible(false);
  var vldPeriod = app.createLabel().setId('vldPeriod').setVisible(false);
  var vldStudentNum = app.createLabel().setId('vldStudentNum').setVisible(false);
  var vldSourceGrp = app.createLabel().setId('vldSourceGrp').setVisible(false);
  var vldTypeGrp = app.createLabel().setId('vldTypeGrp').setVisible(false);
  var vldElementsID = app.createLabel().setId('vldElementsID').setVisible(false);
  var vldQuia = app.createLabel().setId('vldQuia').setVisible(false);

  var btnCreate = app.createButton('Corfirm Event');

  //Add this handler to the button
  var evtHandler = app.getElementById('evtHandler');
  btnCreate.addClickHandler(evtHandler);

  //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
          var formGrid = app.createGrid(13,3).setCellPadding(3);
          vrtMainPanel.add(formGrid);
          formGrid
          .setWidget(0,0,lblSuccess)
          .setWidget(1,0,lblNoSuccess)
          .setWidget(2,0,vldTeacherName)
          .setWidget(3,0,vldExt)
          .setWidget(4,0,vldDate)
          .setWidget(5,0,vldSubject)
          .setWidget(6,0,vldPeriod)
          .setWidget(7,0,vldStudentNum)
          .setWidget(8,0,vldSourceGrp)
          .setWidget(9,0,vldTypeGrp)
          .setWidget(10,0,vldElementsID)
          .setWidget(11,0,vldQuia)
          .setWidget(12,0,btnCreate)

  //Add this panel to the application
      app.add(vrtMainPanel);

      //Return the application
      return app;
}
```

Comment: there are a couple of form validation examples on the forum, for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/google-apps-script-form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload/15303129#15303129  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350114/form-validation-using-client-handler-why-does-input-sequence-order-change-the  , have you already seen it ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been spending a lot of time on form validation and I ended up with 2 possible solutions that work pretty well but since I can't decide which one is the best I use sometimes the first... and sometimes the second...

I'll show the idea of both solution, make your choice.

1. The 'logical' one : use client validation to enable the submit button and a few other client handler validations  to show/hide warning labels near the fields that have to be filled. It works great but I must admit it can be tricky to write the script for it and needs quite a lot of code. (see examples in these post among others : [Form validation on fields and FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/google-apps-script-form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload/15303129#15303129)
   [Form validation using client handler : why does input sequence order change the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350114/form-validation-using-client-handler-why-does-input-sequence-order-change-the)
2. Use a server handler like you did in your code but replace the "createEvent" button with an intermediate button that instead of sending you directly to the event creation function calls a "fake" function that shows a summary of the requested data in a HTML widget with a nice looking presentation and another button that one use to confirm the event creation (and actually create the event) making a sort of 2 steps confirmation that is definitely user friendly. (and includes a way to go back one step to change/append the submitted data.

Both solution as I already said have pro and cons, the second one is just probably easier to write a script for it.

feel free to comment and/or ask for further details if the references I mentioned are not clear enough.

---

EDIT : here is [an example of the 2cond approach](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzIpOOmE9MpeDEVZYdOqUAHzgaLPj3WaJ1M_kpA2jp6FNB_NoI/exec) and the [spreadsheet with the included script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dFd1WEVhMFhYczM5VWpuNDZHQ3AwZEE&usp=sharing) (read only, make a copy to view/edit script and change the spreadsheet ID in the script if you want to run your own version))
The instructions are in french but it shouldn't be too hard to translate ... sorry about that :-)  The SS has a marter sheet where you can define the question in the form and the script generates a custom form. There are tools to count responses, print log sheet per day and send confirmation emails.

Comment: I went with 2nd approach to incorporate a "confirmation page", but have messed something up.  Can you help?  I updated my code above with my current work.

Comment: I don't have a lot of free time this week so I'm not sure I'll be able to do it quickly... but  I'll try...

Comment: Not a problem... thanks for your time. You have been a huge help.