# Google Apps Script - Validating Dates in Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It seems to me that GAS has no feature to do validation besides 'required' in Google Forms.

I have 2 dates. Start Date & End Date.
I'm figuring if there's any way to check and make sure end date is not earlier than start date.

It seems like using UI or HTML form is the way to go. But I just want to see if anyone has other alternatives?

If the answer is no, then I'll probably use this method >
[Form Validation Before Submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231531/form-validation-before-submission)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to check in following manner or not. But, as you said you have two dates, you can validate with following function.

```
function validateDates (startDate, endDate) {

    var diffInMilliSecs = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
    var diffInDays = diffInMilliSecs/1000/60/60/24;
    var diffInDays = Math.round(diffInDays);


  Logger.log('Difference between start date and end date : ' + diffInDays);
    if(Math.abs(diffInDays < -1))
      Logger.log('End date is older than start date');
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the question is how to do this in appsscript to force a valid date range in a google form, not how to write a generic es5 date validation algo.