# Hard stop if a value in a range of cells is not between 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a page where my team could enter data into one page and then hit a save button, then it would copy and paste the data into a database file then clear the contents of the original page. 
What I'm trying to figure out is how I can hard stop the save if the pasted information is incorrect. 
example. they copied the incorrect information from the one program we use and paste it into the spreadsheet. but the customer number is in the wrong cell. 
This would skew the information in the database.

So my thoughts were to have a criteria check of some sort. So it would check the data in a specific column of cells and check to see if it were between 10000 and 99999 or check to ensure it has 5 digits. then have a second check for something similar.

It would be better if I can find a way to have a Paste button that could paste the information and have the hard stop within that code. But baby steps...

```
function Copy() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('file name here'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('InputData');
var range2 = sss.getRange('D8:O1000');
var range = ss.getRange('A8:Q1000');
var data = range.getValues();
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('file name here');
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('OutOfStockData');
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
range2.clearContent();
}
```

Any help would be greatly apricated.

Thanks.

EDIT. 
I'm unable to use forms as we copy the information from an internal WMS program we use. When we copy the information, it gets copied in a format that is recognized by any spreadsheet. So we would just copy and paste into the spreadsheet and then add any extra information needed to each line in the extra columns. (ie. comment column.)
The checks needed is so I can get accurate information on Stockouts. Sometimes an error can be made when one of my teammates copies information from a different window in WMS.  so one check like mentioned before would be customer number which is always in column J. and never more than 99999 or less then 10000. another check could be the Case ID which is always in column D which is never more then 9999999 and less then 1000000. verifying these two columns could prevent the data from being skewed if the wrong information is copied from WMS.

So the Information gets Copied from WMS, Pasted into InputData, then when the added information gets entered I would click the save button and it would take all the data in the inputData sheet and copy it into the outofstockdata sheet where It would be used for other metric data needed.

As far as the Paste button, Some of the guys who would need to use this sheet are not very computer literate. So the goal would be to have them press said Paste button and the information from our WMS program which would be on the clipboard within windows(no different than copying and pasting from an email to a word document). which we have copied earlier be pasted into the Frist sheet where we would comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19231531/1531971 If not, [edit] your question and tell us why.

Comment: @jdv I think he problem is much simpler than that, since he is not using a form and the format of the data is fairly specific. "check to see if it were between 10000 and 99999 or check to ensure it has 5 digits" - very easy to do. "then have a second check for something similar" - we can't see your data or read your mind, you need to tell us exactly what it is you want. "have a Paste button that could paste the information and have the hard stop within that code" - paste the information from where to where?

Comment: Thanks, @JamesD. I've Edited and added more info.

Comment: @SeanG you haven't added an attempt at doing this check, just copied in code copied from a different SO question. Hint: you need to do something with your `data` variable. You'll need a `for` loop, to access array indexes, and `if` statements to perform comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

To hard stop an script that met a condition use `return`. This could be shown with vanilla JavaScript

```js
function myFunction(){
  var upperLimit = 10;
  var lowerLimit = 5;
  var input = prompt('Give me a value');
  // This is the condition that will hard stop the script.
  var condition = input >= lowerLimit && input <= upperLimit; 
  if (condition){
    return; // This hard stop the script.
  } else {
    //if the condition is not met, continue
    myFunction();
  }
}

myFunction();
```