# Auto Increment on Form Submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to add an auto incrementing unique ID with a two digit year prefix to each form submittal.  I have copied the code from Serge Insas's answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428697) and am trying to implement the two-digit year requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863361/add-current-year-to-auto-incrementing-reference-id?rq=1).

```
function OnForm(){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    var startcell = sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
      if(! startcell){sh.getRange('A2').setValue('PQOT-14-0001');return}; // this is only to       handle initial situation when A1 is empty.
    var colValues = sh.getRange('A2:A').getValues();// get all the values in column A in an array
    var year = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "PST", "yy")
    var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
        for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
        var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
          if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in th column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
      }
    max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValue(Utilities.formatString('PQOT-'+year+'-%04d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
}
```

The above code returns "PQOT-14-000X".  I need to edit it to strip out the extraneous text and year so that it will increment properly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substr()` [string method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to get only the last 4 digits using the negative argument : code below :

```
var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().substr(-4).replace(/\D/g,'')
```

Note that I used another variant of the replace [regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to get numerical values D is for any non decimal