# Unique identifier script with Utilities.formatString() only when a new line is added

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to implement a unique identifier in column A. For this, I'm leaning towards the solution which has been discussed here: [Auto incrementing Job Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425728/auto-incrementing-job-reference) (using the Utilities.formatString() in Google sheets).

For ease of reading, here is my current script (I made some slight alterations to the original script):

```
function Identifier(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Epics");
var startcell = sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
var colValues = sh.getRange('A2:A').getValues();// get all the values in column A in an array
var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
  for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
    var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
    if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in the column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
    }
    max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValue(Utilities.formatString('E%04d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
}
```

The original function is designed to work with trigger 'On form submit' but I need this logic to be triggered only when a new line is added to my sheet. Trigger 'On edit' won't work because with that, every change to the sheet results in the last ID to get overwritten with the next new ID.

How can I make sure that my function is only called when a new line is added to the Googlesheet?

Edit [20-Jan.-2015]
Meanwhile I have adapted the script somewhat:

```
function Identifier(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Epics");
var r = ss.getActiveRange();
var editRow = parseInt(r.getRow()); // get the row the edit happend on 
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
var startcell = sh.getRange('A2').getValue();
var colValues = sh.getRange('A2:A').getValues();// get all the values in column A in an array
var max=0;// define the max variable to a minimal value
    if(lastRow == editRow){
        for(var r in colValues){ // iterate the array
        var vv=colValues[r][0].toString().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// remove the letters from the string to convert to number
        if(Number(vv)>max){max=vv};// get the highest numeric value in the column, no matter what happens in the column... this runs at array level so it is very fast
        }
    max++ ; // increment to be 1 above max value
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).setValue(Utilities.formatString('E%04d',max));// and write it back to sheet's last row.
    }
}
```

This almost works as intended. Still to solve:

- With above script, the last ID-Field gets updated with each update to the last line of the sheet. I need an adaptation to above script so that updates in the last line do not result in new ID's. (must have)
- When inserting a new row in an existing range, this is currently not recognised by the script. (nice to have)

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching something along these lines and I can help you with part of your problem. You can create an installed trigger, and use the [OnChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder?hl=en#onChange%28%29) event to trigger when a row is inserted.

```
function myFunction(event){
  if(event.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
    // do Something
  }
}
```

I am still trying to find an answer for the getting the inserted row's location.