# How to generate and where to store unique id for client?

Tags: html, cookies, google-apps-script, uniqueidentifier

I have completely static website (without and backend) with `form`. When user submit's my form I make jsonp request to [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). My GAS handles the request and saves form data to goggle spreadsheet with the following structure:

```
      Name      |     Age     |     City
     ------------------------------------
      Eric      |      23     |     NYC
```

Now I need to store id to unique for each user and store like this:

```
      ClientId  |     Name      |     Age     |     City
     ---------------------------------------------------
      dhs3kwhe  |     Eric      |      23     |     NYC
```

I don't any restrictions about clientId format but the single is that clientId to be unique for any client.

This is similar session id and it would be cool to use it but because I don't have backend I can't generate this one.

What is is the best way to resolve my issue?

**EDIT:**

Let me a little but explain my problem. I need not just generate unique id that I could generate with some algorithms. I need to generate `clientId` for each user. Say `User A` fills and submit form and we generate for him `clientId` like `jshhsd3`. Next time `User A` fills and submit form he has to get the same id `jshhsd3`.

Another `User B` will have own `clientId`when he submit my form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script - unique ID counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397000/google-apps-script-unique-id-counter)

Comment: It seems others have ran into the same problem as you. I linked one of the answers above. one possible option is to append the row number to text that you pass with the form. The accepted answer outlines that solution.

Comment: Another option for you depending on the volume of your app, use UTC timestamp for the ID.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify this problem

Comment: I see. Not sure on your implementation, but have you looked at `getactiveuser()`? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser

Comment: Unfortunately this does't work for me because users, that executes my script through JSONP request, may not to be logged in Google Account. So my scripts available for anonymous users also.

Comment: You just keep throwing on the limitations! ha.I'm not really seeing anything else within the docs that would work without additional API integrations, etc. My only other idea would require trusting the user quite a bit. It may be time to create backend of some sort. You could even go the route of Firebase to handle your "authentication".

Comment: Could you use query params in the URL? This would require that each "client" have a different URL that they submit from. But then you could grab the userid out of the URL, and store it as a hidden value in the form.

Comment: Yes I can. But how to generate userid on a client and shore for user?

Comment: You'd have to come up with a process for that. I'm not familiar with your process for clients & new clients. 1 option is to have a list of client IDs. The user has to select theirs. You then direct them to the link with their id in the URL. Then use jquery or javascript to parse the URL and add it to the form as a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() will give you the unique google email address for each user.

To store each ID? Try:

```
var userId = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();    
scriptProperties.setProperty('username', userId);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does't work for me because users, that executes my script through JSONP request, may not to be logged in Google Account. So my scripts available for anonymous users also