# Visitor File Uploader

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-sites

I have created a Google site for my class, I am trying to place a file uploader on my page. I have found an exemplar codes on the following sites
https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/user-interface/upload-doc
https://sites.google.com/site/toolsclass/apps-scripts/file-uploader (deposits into a specific folder but doesn't seem to work)
but I am a complete novice when it comes to app scripts etc so am in desperate need of a real basic step-by-step set of instructions to get the uploader on my site. If it can also be adapted so that the uploaded files are deposited within a specific folder within my Google Drive then it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of code examples of forms with file upload, [this one for example sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/google-apps-script-form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload/15303129#15303129)ows a full featured form. Try also a search on this forum in the Google-apps-script tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the https://driveuploader.com/ via the iFrame embedding.

This is definitely the easiest way how to receive the files from your web visitors into your Google Drive.