# Dynamic behavior in Google forms using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am creating a Google forms **page** which ends with a file upload button. This file upload button should get enabled once the above existing form items like check box, text field, etc  are validated. How can this be achieved using AppsScript in Google Forms? I couldn't file any resource that shows how to validate fields in a form.

Answer (score 0):

The live form can only be static. You can not cause the layout or elements of the live form to change. You can only make changes to the master form and republish the live form.

There is built in validation with forms:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en

Comment: Is there a way I can allow/not allow them to a next/new form based on their responses on page 1?

Comment: I am surprised that I cannot create events based on user input in forms. Thanks for sharing validation part though. Is there any work around for what am trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnujBalan you can write a webapp instead of using forms.

Comment: @Anuj possible duplicate SO question. You can refer to the answer in the [ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/google-apps-script-form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload)