# Validating Response Text in a Form via Google Apps Script/RegEx

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have a [Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1GT77hzGhGQ9gjgXS3QeiKkU2amL3cChKY__qvqccRak/edit).  I am trying to set multiple validation criteria for several of the questions.  Here are the validation criteria I'm trying to set by question:

**/PC - Pilot Callsign**

- Starts with "FCB"
- 6 or 7 characters long
- The last 3 characters must be numbers
- If it is 7 characters long, the 4th character must also be a number that isn't 0

**/TM - Time**

- 4 characters long
- First two characters only integers between 00 and 23, inclusive
- First two characters only integers between 00 and 59, inclusive

**/TP - Aircraft Type**

- 4 characters long

**/FL - Flight Level**

- 5 characters long
- Starts with "FL"
- Last 3 digits are numbers

**/BT - Block Time**

- At least 3 characters long
- Period is second to last character
- All characters preceding the period or after the period must be numbers

I tried programming this with Google Apps Script:

```
function pirep() {

var item = "flyCaribbean PIREP"
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()

  // Urgency
item = "/UA - Urgent"
var choices = ["UA - Routine", "UUA - Urgent"]
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle(item)
    .setChoiceValues(choices)
    .setRequired(true)  

 // Pilot Callsign
item = "/PC - Pilot Callsign"
form.addTextItem()
    .setTitle(item)
    .setRequired(true);
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .requireTextContainsPattern("FCB")
item.setHelpText("In the format: 'FCB001' or 'FCB2905'.")
item.setValidation(textValidation) }
```

I need help getting started with data validation via the apps script or RegEx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**/PC - Pilot Callsign**

([F][C][B])([0-9][0-9][0-9])([0-9]|)

**/TP - Aircraft Type**

(....)

**/TM - Time**

(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(([0-5][0-9]))

**/TP - Flight Level**

([F][L])([0-9][1-9][0-9]|[1-9]

**/BT - Block Time**

(([0-9]|)[0-9][.][0-9])

Answer (score 1):

Most of those rules you listed looked to me like they could be handled within the form itself using the regular expressions option within the response validation tool.  You can set response validation within the form for each question.

If you haven't looked at that, here are a couple of links to get you started:

1. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en
2. https://www.labnol.org/internet/regular-expressions-forms/28380/

Comment: Thank you!  Is there still a way to do this in code?

Comment: No problem.  There probably is a way to do this using code, but I think you would have to write the entire form yourself from scratch.  For e.g. in this post the OP is trying to validate data in a form written from scratch - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302510/form-validation-on-fields-and-fileupload?noredirect=1&lq=1.    Here's a link to documentation on using regular expressions in javascript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.  If you found my answer useful, would appreciate it if you voted it up.  Ta.